# Custom action in Nemo (Linux Mint 18.3, Cinnamon) are not visible in menu

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nemo

I am trying to add custom action in Nemo's menu. For this I put file `my-action.nemo_action` in `~/.local/share/nemo/actions` like this:

```
[Nemo Action]

Active=true
Name=Energize %N
Comment=My custom, fancy action
Exec=<my-action.bash %F>
Icon-Name=folder
Selection=Any
Extensions=Any
EscapeSpaces=true
Quote=double
```

and I put `my-action.bash` in the same folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${@}" >/dev/pts/0;
```

(This is supposed to send %F to my opened terminal with proper number). Bash script has 764 mode and Nemo action has 664 mode. Nemo has been restarted (`nemo -q`), but `Energize %N` never appears in context menu. `actions` directory has 775 mode. Any clues what did I miss?

I ran Nemo in debug mode, but there's nothing about my custom action whatsoever.

Comment: Seems like `Selection=Any` was the problem. `Selection=NotNone` solved the problem. Still don't know what is the difference btw `NotNone` and `Any`. BTW `m` (multiple) apparently does not include single selection.